# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: javax.swing.JFrame.setContentPaneel

Tags: java

http://puu.sh/hLNH1/74b40dff89.png

I have tried googling this issue for many hours been asking around on Skype I haven't found the solution yet. So I think it's time to ask professional developers what's going on.

Alright so I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: javax.swing.JFrame.setContentPaneel
>     at Vb0301.main(Vb0301.java:11)

I've just started to learn Java for my study and the cody provided in the Puush link is a direct copy from the book.

I know it has something to do with:

```
frame.setContentPaneel(new Paneel() );
```

So I tried switching it from that to:

```
frame.setContentPane(new Paneel() );
```

But at this point I get new errors link: http://puu.sh/hLNVU/c760502ca9.png

It's starting to annoy the heck out of me to setup IDE in the first place the last couple of days have been errors after errors...

I hope someone is able to help I've been looking around here but didn't find the specific question. I hope to get replies soon, thanks in advance.

Naomi,

Comment: But that is so odd because in the book I'm learning from they use **Paneel** instead of **Panel** So I changed it to Panel but there is still errors : http://puu.sh/hLQd7/e27bfeff7b.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong class name. `Paneel` does not exist, it should be `Panel` instead.

Also, the method you are calling is called `setContentPane()`. See [the reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setContentPane(java.awt.Container)) for more information.

**Edit:** As you can see in the comments on this answer, the problem was in the `Panel` class (but not as stated above).
`Panel` has to extend `JPanel` to allow it to be added to the frame.

Comment: In the OP `Paneel` does exist, but it is a `JFrame`.

Comment: But that is so odd because in the book I'm learning from they use **Paneel** instead of **Panel** So I changed it to Panel but there is still errors : http://puu.sh/hLQd7/e27bfeff7b.png

Comment: I see your class `Panel` extends `JFrame`. Try extending `JPanel` instead.

Comment: @Hexaholic, thank you so much bro it's finally working!!

Comment: @Naomi I'm glad it's working. I updated my answer, would you mind accepting it?

Comment: @Naomi You just did it, thank you ;) For more information on accepting answers, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

It should be `frame.setContentPane(new Paneel())` - more on [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setContentPane%28java.awt.Container%29).

Here `Paneel` should be a container like `JPanel`. More on `JPanel`- [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's because it's not allowed to add a JFrame with setContentPane(), it expects a container like it checks here :

```
 /**
 * Checks that the component is not a Window instance.
 */
private void checkNotAWindow(Component comp){
    if (comp instanceof Window) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("adding a window to a container");
    }
}
```